# How to include file name in footnote of pdf file?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

Is it possible to add pdf file name to footnote of each page of this file? Possibly with use of pdfunite or pdftk?

Comment: Are you creating the PDF, or modifying an existing one?

Comment: modifying an existing one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use STAMPtk with PDFtk to add headers, footers, watermarks
and stamps to PDF documents.

You need to prepare a PDF with empty pages that contains only the new
footnotes. The last page of this file is duplicated to the the rest of the
source PDF, if the new PDF is shorter.

The next command uses `pdftk` with `multistamp` to overlay the page numbering file to an original:

```
pdftk original.pdf              \
  multistamp 100pagenumbers.pdf \
  output pages-numbered.pdf
```

For more information see:

- [How to Add Headers, Footers, Watermarks and Stamps to PDF](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/how-to-add-headers-footers-watermarks-and-stamps-to-pdf/)
- [Modify existing PDF to add "Page N of NNN" footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378713/modify-existing-pdf-to-add-page-n-of-nnn-footer/30416992#30416992)